# Position hover-over circle exactly over X

Tags: html, css

I am trying to perfectly position a perfectly round circle directly over the "X" upon hover-over. How to make that work?

```css
.select2-selection__clear {
 font-size:20px;
 padding-right:10px;
}

.select2-selection__clear:hover {
 background-color:#000;
 color:#FFF;
 width:20px;
 height:20px;
 -moz-border-radius: 20px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
 border-radius: 20px;
}
```

```html
<span class="select2-selection__clear">×</span>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This way:

```css
.select2-selection__clear {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
}

.select2-selection__clear:hover {
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<span class="select2-selection__clear">×</span>
```

This is better than setting padding, because it is more universal. Text inside may change, but the layout will not break (and the circle will actually be a circle).

Answer (score 1):

Try giving an equal padding on left and right:

```
.select2-selection__clear {
    font-size:20px;
    padding-right:5px;
    padding-left:5px;
}
```